# Search is not working in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, search

I am facing a issue with the Tridion Search, It stops working frequently.

When I check the Event Viewer, I get the below Error:

> Unable to get the list of search results. Sending a request to the
>   Search Engine at http://localhost:8983/tridion failed with the
>   following response: The connection can not be established.

The Tridion Search Host & Search Indexer services are running properly. But If I run the start.bat file from Tridion_Home/solr-jetty folder, then again the http://localhost:8983/tridion URL becomes up and search works properly.

Any reason for the URL to go down frequently & any solution for this?

Comment: I'd suggest you to check the solr logs something like  {TRIDION}\log\2015_07_15.jetty.log.

Comment: {TRIDION}\log\2015_07_15.jetty.log is not created

Answer (score 2):

This issue might happen up if there is any other service/process on the service is occupying the 8983 port.
I would suggest, whenever this happens (the Tridion Search is not working), try the following command on the Command Prompt to check for the various ports used by processes -

```
netstat -n -a -o
```

This command will list down all the ports and associated processes with the port - verify that 8983 port is not been occupied by any other process by forcefully.
If it is the case, you may either choose to alter that specific process to use any other port (Recommended) or choose to change the port used by Tridion's Solr Instance.

Comment: I have checked the command and no other process is forcefully occupying the port.